# Edit XML from SQL, insert in for-loop issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am trying to modify an XML contained in a sql server table using xQuery. One particular node in this XML contains several nodes of the same type. What I am trying to do is to insert a node element containing the order of this node as an integer.

This is the initial situation

```
DECLARE @xml XML= N'
<parentNode>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
</parentNode>'
```

and this is what I want to achieve

```
<parentNode>
   <node>
          <Number> 1 </Number>
   </node>
   <node>
          <Number> 2 </Number>
   </node>
   <node>
          <Number> 3 </Number>
   </node>
</parentNode>
```

I have been trying to do this using the for-loop "for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1" which gives me the number of each node, but I fail to insert the numbers.

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved (preferably using xQuery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first get the number of nodes and insert that many child number nodes using `XQUERY'

```
DECLARE @xml XML= N'
<parentNode>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
</parentNode>'

declare @nodes int = @xml.value('count(/parentNode/node)','INT')
declare @newnode XML
declare @nodeCount int =1
while @nodeCount <= @nodes
begin

set @newnode = ( select @nodeCount as 'Number' FOR XML PATH(''))
select @newnode
set @xml.modify('insert sql:variable("@newnode") into (/parentNode/node[sql:variable("@nodeCount")])[1]')
set @nodeCount = @nodeCount +1
end
select @xml
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @xml XML= N'
<parentNode>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
</parentNode>'

declare @cnt int=0
declare @counter int=1

select 
  @cnt=@xml.value('count(/parentNode/node)','int')

declare @newXml nvarchar(max)
set @newXml=N'<parentNode>'
while (@counter <= @cnt)
begin
set @newXml = @newXml + '<node><Number>'+cast(@counter as varchar(10)) +'</Number></node>'
set @counter=@counter+1
end
set @newXml=@newXml+'</parentNode>'
select convert(xml,@newXml)
```

*Output:*

```
<parentNode>
  <node>
    <Number>1</Number>
  </node>
  <node>
    <Number>2</Number>
  </node>
  <node>
    <Number>3</Number>
  </node>
</parentNode>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this solution does not in fact use the initial XML at all, but rather constructs it from scratch? This is impractical to me as the actual XML is much more complex than the given example. I would also much rather use xQuery than treat the XML as a string.